# Vector iterator is not incrementable

Tags: c++

Why am I getting a `Vector iterator is not incrementable` error in this code?

```
for (vector<vector<Point>>::iterator it = contours.begin(); it != contours.end(); ++it) {
    if (contourArea(*it) < 50) {
        it = contours.erase(it);
    }
}
```

The other answers I looked at said to solve this error by assigning the iterator that `.erase()` returns to `it`, but I'm still getting the same error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your code has two problems:

1. It skips an element when you erase an element.
2. It runs in to a problem (leading to undefined behavior) if you call `erase` on the last element of the vector.

Here's what you should use:

```
for (vector<vector<Point>>::iterator it = contours.begin(); it != contours.end(); ) {
    if (contourArea(*it) < 50) {
        it = contours.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```